# List index out of range error for loop on Json

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to request a json object and run through the object with a for loop and take out the data I need and save it to a model in django.

I only want the first two attributes of `runner_1_name` and `runner_2_name` but in my json object the amount or runners varies inside each list. I keep getting list index out of range error.  I have tried to use try and accept but when I try save to the model it's showing my save variables is referenced before assignment What's the best way of ignoring list index out or range error or fixing the list so the indexes are correct? I also want the code to run really fast as I will using this function as a background task to poll every two seconds.

```
@shared_task()
def mb_get_events():
mb = APIClient('username' , 'pass')
tennis_events = mb.market_data.get_events()

for data in tennis_events:
id = data['id']
event_name = data['name']

sport_id = data['sport-id']
start_time = data['start']
is_ip = data['in-running-flag']

par = data['event-participants']
event_id = par[0]['event-id']

cat_id = data['meta-tags'][0]['id']
cat_name = data['meta-tags'][0]['name']
cat_type = data['meta-tags'][0]['type']
url_name = data['meta-tags'][0]['type']

try:
    runner_1_name = data['markets'][0]['runners'][0]['name']
except IndexError:
      pass
 try: 
    runner_2_name = data['markets'][0]['runners'][1]['name']
 except IndexError:
      pass

run1_par_id = data['markets'][0]['runners'][0]['id']
run2_par_id = data['markets'][0]['runners'][1]['id']

run1_back_odds = data['markets'][0]['runners'][0]['prices'][0]['odds'] 
run2_back_odds = data['markets'][0]['runners'][1]['prices'][0]['odds'] 
run1_lay_odds = data['markets'][0]['runners'][0]['prices'][3]['odds'] 
run2_lay_odds = data['markets'][0]['runners'][1]['prices'][3]['odds'] 

te, created = MBEvent.objects.update_or_create(id=id)
te.id = id
te.event_name = event_name
te.sport_id = sport_id
te.start_time = start_time
te.is_ip = is_ip
te.event_id = event_id
te.runner_1_name = runner_1_name
te.runner_2_name = runner_2_name
te.run1_back_odds = run1_back_odds
te.run2_back_odds = run2_back_odds
te.run1_lay_odds = run1_lay_odds
te.run2_lay_odds = run2_lay_odds
te.run1_par_id = run1_par_id
te.run2_par_id = run2_par_id
te.cat_id = cat_id
te.cat_name = cat_name
te.cat_type = cat_type
te.url_name = url_name
te.save()
```

Comment: can you explain your problem explicitly ? your code is too much to read, send the specific part that has problem

Comment: also if you could format your code as well, it would be great. its unreadable at the moment.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi i'm trying to figure out a better way to deal with list index out or ranger error. on the variables `runner_1_name` and `runner_2_name` the list sizes vary and i only want the first two elements in the runners list

Comment: can you show the `markets` part of your json.

Comment: send me one row of `tennis_events` so that i can help you

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi @Vaibhav Vishal Here is a gist to the output data from `tennis_events`
https://gist.github.com/Hey-tom/5dd6d61c7cfb28700405e6efd1ea5e7b

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi here's a gist to one row which might be easier to check https://gist.github.com/Hey-tom/dba0638245eb55dea42de00b0321cac5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Fix:**

```
try:
    runner_1_name = data['markets'][0]['runners'][0]['name']
except IndexError:
    runner_1_name = ''  # don't just pass here
try: 
    runner_2_name = data['markets'][0]['runners'][1]['name']
except IndexError:
  runner_2_name = ''
```

It giving you `variables is referenced before assignment` because in expect block you are just passing, so if try fails `runner_1_name` or `runner_2_name` is never defined. You when you try to use those variables you get an error because they were never defined. So in except block either set the value to a blank string or some other string like `'Runner Does not Exists'`.

---

Now if you want to totally avoid try/except and `IndexError` you can use `if` statements to check the length of `markets` and `runners`. Something like this:

```
runner_1_name = ''
runner_2_name = ''
# Make sure markets exists in data and its length is greater than 0 and runners exists in first market
if 'markets' in data and len(data['markets']) > 0 and 'runners' in data['market'][0]:
    runners = data['markets'][0]['runners']
    # get runner 1
    if len(runners) > 0 and `name` in runners[0]:
        runner_1_name = runners[0]['name']
    else:
        runner_1_name = 'Runner 1 does not exists'
    # get runner 2
    if len(runners) > 1 and `name` in runners[1]:
        runner_2_name = runners[1]['name']
    else:
        runner_2_name = 'Runner 2 does not exists'
```

As you can see this gets too long and its not the recommended way to do things.
You should just assume data is alright and try to get the names and use try/except to catch any errors as suggested above in my first code snippet.

Comment: thanks for your answer I if i was to do the same to 'run1_back_odds' which is a float how would I store the exception? I've tried to run the code but I'm getting a value error could not convert string to float

Comment: let me check it.

Comment: set it to 0 instead of an empty string (`' '`)

Comment: also instead of getting runner 1 and runner 2 data like this, you should make a function to which returns all data of a runner in a dict, and you should then pass runner[0] and runner[1] to that function. that will cut your code in half.

Comment: You can also update or create in one line then using `MBEvent.objects.update_or_create(**dict)`, just be sure uniqueness is enforced properly in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with a list of comments that can be empty or filled by an unknown number of comments

My solution is to initialize a counting variable at 0 and have a while loop on a boolean 
In the loop I try to get comment[count] if it fails on except IndexError I set the boolean to False to stop the infinite loop

```
count = 0
condition_continue = True

while condition_continue :
    try:
        detailsCommentDict = comments[count]
        ....
    except IndexError:
        # no comment at all or no more comment
        condition_continue = False
```